# Onclick of Clear Button, remove data from data table

Tags: reactjs

When I search for a name, the list of results automatically populates my table. What I want to do is when I click the clear button, I want my table to be cleared. Not deleted.

I haven't started my code yet but I just need an idea about the clear button. You don't necessarily need to give me code :)

Comment: What you want to do is populate the table with dynamic content from a state, then when this content is updated (e.g. becomes the empty string `""`) the table would re-render without content. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the list of results in the state and simply reset the state to an empty array when you click the button. Something like this:

```
  this.state = {
    data: []
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch("/api/your-url").then(data => this.setState({data}));
  }

  render(){
    return(
      //display your data in a table
      this.state.data.map(row => {
        return(
          //html markup
        )
      })
      <button onClick={() => this.setState({data: []})}>Clear data</button>
    );
  }
```

Comment: this would delete saved data and you would need to use api call again in order to present data one more time.

Comment: Yes it will but that's what he was asking for. Clear the table but not delete it. If this was referring to delete only one record in the table then yes, I'll update my answer.

Comment: yup, this is exactly what I need. Thanks for this!

Comment: You can mark the answer as correct if it helped you. :)